# Winter '17 Apex Email Limits: What counts?

Tags: email, limits, singleemailmessage

Salesforce has raised the daily limit for apex emails from 1k to 5k, which is fantastic. The email limits have always contained this clause:

> There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your org directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

Does anyone know what feature this refers to? Is this just referring to the standard "Send an Email" button on record detail pages? I have run tests in DE orgs and emails sent via apex using `setTargetObjectId` instead of `setToAddresses` have always seemed to count against the daily limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase only applies to emails sent through the user interface directly. Emails sent by other means are subject to the limits. Keep in mind that emailing users via setTargetObjectId does not count as part of this limit. You can email your users as often and frequently as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had figured as much. The unfortunate part about emailing a user via setTargetObjectId is that the platform does not also allow you to set a related object for the email, meaning that your emails have to be mostly static and simplistic.

Comment: Adding to this, although you can send more than the limit using targetibjectid it still reduces your ability to send to external. For example if you send 999 using target object id you can only send 1 more to external address but can send as many as needed using targetibjectid. It's a bit convoluted. That is unless it has changed since my tests around this a year ago.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @Eric. This is one area of Salesforce that I feel is very specific, but not documented well at all.

Answer (score -1):

In Developer Edition orgs and orgs evaluating Salesforce during a trial period, you can send mass email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day. This lower limit doesn’t apply if your org was created before the Winter ’12 release and already had mass email enabled with a higher limit. Additionally, your org can send single emails to a maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

find more information here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm

Comment: This doesn't help answer my question about what counts against the limit and what the exception clause pertains to.